# ASP.Net Core SignalR simple host - 404 error

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I am wanting to have 1 simple console app host that is solely for self-hosting the SignalR component.

I have created an "Empty Web Application" using the template. I have created a very simple StartUp file that does not contain anything like MVC etc as it is not needed. However I am getting a 404 not found error from the browser when attempting to negotiate.

The Startup file is as follows:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<Masterhub>("masterhub");
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is very basic, but as I don't want any MVC/Web API functionality, I didn't include all of that setup. There is setup for CORS and SignalR, that is all.

Is what I am attempting to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the JavaScript file I was using from the web client to connect to the self-hosted SignalR Console Application, was the old full .Net version, and not the new version you can get from NPM.